# VS2015 - Vnext Run functional task with Nunit does not consider the test filter criteria

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit, vnext

In `VSTS 2015` we have build and release pipeline setup in a project which is using `NUnit` test framework. We are trying to configure Integration test case execution using `Visual Test Agent Deployment Task` and `Run Functional Task`

`Visual Test Agent Deployment Task` is used to Deploy the Test Agent in target machine. The Agent deployment task is getting executed successfully

`Run Functional Test` is also executing all the `NUnit` tests from `dll` successfully if I don't provide any test case filter.

Now I want to execute specific tests by `category filter`. But when I provide the TestCaseFilter criteria as `TestCategory=Regresison`, the run get aborted in `Run Functional Test` with below messages:

```
[warning]DistributedTests: Test Run Discovery Aborted . Test run id : 846680

[warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.

[warning]DistributedTests: Error : NUnit Adapter 3.4.0.0: Test discovery complete
```

It looks run functional test task does not consider the filter for `NUnit` tests. As run functional test using VSTest console command internally. I tried that on the agent VM and I am able to execute the same from command prompt on test agent vm using command

```
Vstest.console.exe test.dll  /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=Regression"
```

Can anyone help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is : Category=CategoryName